Overdrive installment
I have a Toyota Sprinter Ae100. I recently changed my gearbox. Previously the gearbox was not overdrive one and I put the overdrive one. What do I need to make the overdrive work and is the overdrive default on or off

Is this a standard or automatic shift transmission?
